# Assigning Peaks and Determining J Values for Mata-Disubstituted Benzene

Tags: aromatic-compounds, nmr-spectroscopy

I need to determine as many J values as I can for 3-methoxybenzaldehyde. The peaks overlap a lot, and I don't see the expected ddd or dt pattern that I would expect for the hydrogen on carbon 6. The HSQC I was given has the clearest peaks for the H NMR, so I attached that. Maybe someone with more NMR experience can help me tease apart the signals?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's almost nothing you can do in this situation, unfortunately. Because of strong coupling and other issues, aromatic peaks often do not conform to the so-called $n+1$ rule, which makes it highly non-trivial to extract coupling constants. It is probably possible to "fit" coupling constants to the multiplet shape by simulating the spectrum for a given set of $J$'s and seeing which set best matches the observed spectrum.

The HSQC trace is unfortunately not useful in this regard. At first glance, it may look simpler than the 1D proton spectrum you undoubtedly have. But that is because HSQC spectra are invariably recorded with low resolution in the proton dimension. The main reason for that is because of the high-power <sup>13</sup>C decoupling that is performed during the acquisition. Acquisition times therefore need to be kept to approximately 100 ms, or there is a serious risk of damaging the spectrometer. On the other hand, a 1D proton spectrum doesn't utilise <sup>13</sup>C decoupling, and can have acquisition times of several seconds.

Assuming the spectral width is constant, a shorter acquisition time means poorer resolution (this is a property of the discrete Fourier transform).

Comment: The last point "Assuming the spectral width is constant, a shorter acquisition time means poorer resolution (this is a property of the discrete Fourier transform)." is very critical. The readers should keep in mind that the resolution with shorter acquisition time is poorer because of the frequency spacing with lesser number of data points. Larger the length of the data, smaller the frequency spacing on the x-axis.